# Are there any guides for what ingredients would be needed to make a magic item, spell, or how long to research the spell to make it?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, spell-components, spell-slots

I’m planning to send my players on quests to get ingredients for a very powerful shield to protect a plane.  Are there any guides or recommendations for the difficulty(CR) that magic items of certain rarities would require to be made?

Common, uncommon, rare, very rare, legendary, artifacts, and items that are even stronger than artifacts in terms of abilities.

Examples:

1. Something like the rod of absorption, but able to hold many more
   levels of spells.
2. A staff that when planted into the ground, causes a massive volcano
   to form,
3. a magical array that makes a 50 mile diameter sphere have positive
   energy suffusing it(giving a bonus to the health gained when
   spending hit die or by resting)

#### And for spells, a similar question.

Are there guides for players to create new spells or one time use scrolls or rituals that include the CR of the adventure to acquire them? 
Examples

1. An enhanced version of glyph of warding that can hold all the way up
   to ninth or even more powerful spells
2. A spell to make a incredibly large gate, large enough to trap a
   tarrasque in Acheron or Ysgard.
3. An enhanced version of wish with fewer limitations.

#### Research

1. Finally, are there rules on how long you must take to research a new
   spell?

Comment: You have three separate questions here. Please move the question about spells and research into two questions, and by all means link back to this one.  I edited this for format since you piled it all into one paragraph.  As I was editing it I realized that you are covering more than one topic.  Also, do you have a copy of the Dungeon Masters Guide?  (You might want to explain why you think *wish* needs an enhancement when you move that question over)

Comment: Worth noting that the only limit on *glyph of warding*’s capacity to hold a strong spell is the caster’s number of spell slots. A caster with 2 9th level slots could cast *glyph of warding* with one and another 9th level with another.

Comment: Related: [How much would it cost to make this magic item?](/questions/84039), [Are there requirement for crafting magic items?](/questions/51630), [Using downtime activity to research spells](/questions/58495)

Comment: This question contains *at least* three distinct questions that need to be split up into separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

In Xanathar’s Guide to Everything, pages 128-130, the details of crafting magical items are listed. This is more what you’re looking for, it sounds, than the more general rules in the Dungeon Master’s Guide, pages 128-129.

Creating a spell is found in the Dungeon Master’s Guide, starting on page 283.

Creating magic items stronger than Legendary is not detailed, nor is creating spells stronger than 9th level. That Is under DM purview.

Answer (score 0):

There are some guidelines in Xanathar's Guide To Everything, in "Downtime Revisited" under "Crafting an Item".

It's all pretty vague, because this is pretty much "Whatever the story needs" territory and the DM is suppose to come up with something that fits their campaign. But it does have a nice little table that links each rarity to a range of Challenge Ratings that need to be overcome and some tips for how to do it.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if you included a reference to the DMG stuff on crafting stuff as well.